# How to mathematically find principal axes frame for a random distribution of mass $\rho(r)$?

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

How to mathematically find principal axes frame for a random distribution of mass with density $\rho(r)$? That was, how to find the origin and orthonormal basis such that the moment of inertial matrix was diagonalized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any Cartesian coordinate system to compute the moment of inertia tensor. It will be symmetric.

Find its eigenvectors and eigenvalues, considering it as a matrix. The eigenvectors give the directions of the principal axes in the original coordinate system. Because the matrix is symmetric, they will be orthogonal; you can of course normalize them so they have unit length.

The eigenvalues give you the values on the diagonal of the diagonalized matrix.